# PHP date() shows tomorrow's date

Tags: php

I have an odd error.
If I call:

```
 date("js M")
```

it shows tomorrow's date, I don't know what changed because yesterday that function was working just fine. 
I haven't tested anything in production, as far as I can see, it only happens in localhost.

I already checked my clock and it is right, is there any other place where PHP fetches the date? What could have changed? 
Thank you!

Comment: When you say you've checked your clock, do you mean the one on the server that's returning this?  Also, does the timezone for the web server/PHP match that of the server.  Had a similar problem a few years back with two servers where the timezone on one was set to Sydney and the other to Melbourne, and then Daylight Savings kicked in and suddenly they were returning results an hour apart.

Comment: Yes, I meant the one returning that. 
That clock was set to "August 7th, 2012" (Today's date for reference in the future), but the function was displaying "August 8th, 2012"
It surprised me a bit because yesterday was working just fine, and I am the only one who mess with the server (as far as I know), and I haven't touched the timezone configuration at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By Default the `date()` function uses a unix timestamp, which is always set to +0:00.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

If you set the default timezone, the unix timestamp used will apply the correct offset to your location and you should be getting the correct day for you no matter where you are.

Comment: bit short in the explanation, but indeed probably a timezone issue.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But what could have caused to change the timezone? I haven't touched the configuration at all.

Comment: @PeterVR I edited the answer and added some info as to why that works and what it does.