# Virus causing wrong date to display

Tags: php, date, system, virus

I have a basic php script

```
<?php

$today = date("Y-m-d");

echo $today;

?>
```

Which should output 2014-11-14. However, I am getting output of 2014-11-15 even though my system tray displays 2014-11-14.

I changed the system date back one day (13th) and I got the output I wanted (14th)... Earlier today I had to do a system restore and ran Malwarebytes because I picked up a virus. Could this be the cause of this?

Does anyone know where else I can check my systems time other than the system tray?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11854861/3933332

Comment: @Rizier123 add it as an answer. This is the exact same problem, probably report as a duplicate too. This is a problem with the timezone settings

Comment: thanks everyone. sorry its a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`date()` function uses unix timestamps which always is set to +0:00

So use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zurich');
```

When you set your default timezone it will automaticly calculate the offset!

Answer (score 0):

the date() function is returning UTC time and not the time on your local computer